# Is there a javascript implementation of MediaPipe's Palm Tracking?

Tags: mediapipe, tensorflow.js

I found a javascript implementation of MediaPipe's FaceMesh and HandPose but not Palm Tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They currently do not have a javascript API for hand tracking.